# What does it mean If I’m asked to find a solution set for a single equation

Tags: linear-algebra

For homework I have a question where I’m asked to find a solution set for a single equation which equals 0, and then to figure out conditions for whether it’s a subspace. I was just wondering what the solution set would look like for just one equation? I’m confused since obviously normal RREF won’t woke and Ax = 0 seems to not work.

Comment: Solution set for a single equation is the set of values from the reference set that satisfy the given equation.

Comment: @PranavGupta53535 so it’s potentially an infinite set?

Comment: Definitely yes. For example, if you have to find all real numbers $x$ satisfying $3x<4$, your solution set would include all real numbers less than $\frac43$, which makes it an infinite set.

Comment: What is the equation you are given?

Comment: @Arthur It would be unethical to give the equation. This is practice for a test, so I have to approach through figuring out good general questions to ask otherwise I won’t learn.

Comment: We can't help you figuring out how to solve something if all you're telling us is that it is an equation. If you tell us what equation it is, we can help you understand how that type of equation is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the techniques that you’ve learned *do* work with a single equation. Aside from being less work since the coefficient matrix starts off in echelon form, it’s no different from working with any other system of equations with fewer equations than unknowns.

Every zero in the single row of the coefficient matrix corresponds to a free variable—the equation doesn’t constrain them at all. The corresponding standard basis vector is therefore a basis vector for the solution space. Turning to the non-zero entries, the leftmost one is your pivot: it corresponds to a free variable, $x_k$ and the remaining non-zero entries are all dependent variables. For each dependent variable in turn, set the others to zero to get an equation for that variable in terms of $x_k$. This will give you another solution set basis vector for each dependent variable. After computing one or two of these basis vectors, you should see a simple pattern emerge.

For example, suppose we’re working in $\mathbb R^5$ and our equation is $2x_2+3x_3-4x_5=0$. The coefficient matrix is $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&2&3&0&-4\end{bmatrix}.$$ The two zero entries gives us the basis vectors $\mathbf e_1$ and $\mathbf e_4$. Our pivot column is the second, so $x_2$ is a free variable. Setting $x_4=0$ we get $2x_2+3x_3=0$, so $x_3=-\frac23x_2$, so $\left(0,1,-\frac23,0,0\right)^T$ is another basis vector for the solution set. Similarly, for $x_5$ we get the vector $\left(0,1,0,0,\frac12\right)^T$. Putting all this together, one description of the solution set is the span of these four vectors, i.e., it consists of vectors of the form $\left(a,c+d,-\frac23c,b,\frac12d\right)^T$.

Here’s another way to think about this example: the solution set consists of all of the vectors that are orthogonal to $\mathbf n = (0,2,3,0,-4)^T$ with respect to the standard dot product, i.e., the equation is equivalent to $\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf x=0$. The solution space is the orthogonal complement of the span of $\mathbf n$, so it is four-dimensional: we need four independent vectors for a basis. An easy way to generate these four vectors is to pick a nonzero element of $\mathbf n$ and swap its negation with each other element in turn, setting the rest to zero. In this case, we can choose the $2$, for which this procedure generates $(-2,0,0,0,0)^T$, $(0,3,-2,0,0)^T$, $(0,0,0,-2,0)^T$ and $(0,-4,0,0,-2)^T$. These are obviously scalar multiples of the four vectors obtained previously.

Answer (score 0):

A linear equation $ Ax = O $ always have the solution $ x = 0 $.

however, if $ A $ does not have full rank, you can find more solutions. (and they are infinite)

since the solution set is {$x \in V | Ax = O$}, you can find out that it is equivalent to the null space of the given matrix $ A $. (easy to check that this set is a subspace of $ V $)

for an $ m \times n $ matrix, if $ n $ is larger than $ m $, then the solution space (or the null space) has dimension at least $ n - m $, due to the dimension theorem.

hope that these information can help you.